# Is there any limitation to create zone do domains outside US, like Brazilian Domains?

Tags: dns, cloud, google-cloud-platform, zone, google-cloud-dns

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform and want to use Google Cloud DNS. Is there any limitation to create zone do domains outside US, like Brazilian Domains?

When I tried to create a managed-zone but occurs error 400 (Bad Request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google Cloud DNS does not limit creating zones outside of the US. For instance, there are users with Danish domains (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-dns-discuss/ORMHiAuA4uY)

Include the command that you tried and the full error message if you would like more assistance.